# Php add the coma with duople quetes in json string

Tags: php

I tried this code

```
foreach($comment as $cmd)
    {
        $dids=$cmd['qid'];
        $json = json_encode($dids);
    }   echo($json);
```

my output like this

```
"1""2"
```

how to add the comma between these string

I want my output `"1","2"`

please help me

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick:

```
<?php
    $dids = array();
    foreach($comment as $cmd) {
        $dids[]=$cmd['qid'];
    }
    $json = json_encode($dids);
    echo($json);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to append comma manually

```
foreach($comment as $cmd) {
    $dids=$cmd['qid'];
    $json = json_encode($dids) . ",";
}
```

Thanks
Amit

Comment: answer is came but how to remove the last comma my output like these "1","2",

Comment: use <?php echo rtrim($json,","); ?> @A.C.Manikandan

Answer (score 1):

use this code instead:

```
    foreach($comment as $cmd){
    $dids=$cmd['qid'];
    $json = json_encode($dids).",";
}echo substr($json,0,strlen($json)-1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here it works

```
  foreach($comment as $cmd) {
        $dids=$cmd['qid'];
        $dids=$dids.",";
        $json = json_encode($dids);
    }
```